# Upgraded glassfish 3.1.2.2 to Mojara 2.2.8-03, EL functions in composite components stop working

Tags: jsf, glassfish, el, composite-component, mojarra

I've updated glassfish 3.1.2.2 to Mojarra 2.2.8-03 by copying the new javax.faces.jar and javax.el.jar to the $GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/modules directory.  After redeploying my application, I've found that the function of:concat is no longer being resolved - when I try to render JSF pages with this code I get the following error.  I was wondering where I've gone wrong, I imagine I've forgotten up grade a library or our project pom.xml.  This is on a dev machine, using netbeans to deploy.

**Exception thrown**

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Function 'of:concat' not found
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary$UserComponentHandlerFactory.createHandler(AbstractTagLibrary.java:344)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.AbstractTagLibrary.createTagHandler(AbstractTagLibrary.java:723)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.CompositeTagLibrary.createTagHandler(CompositeTagLibrary.java:194)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TagUnit.createFaceletHandler(TagUnit.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TextUnit.createFaceletHandler(TextUnit.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CompilationUnit.getNextFaceletHandler(CompilationUnit.java:115)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.TagUnit.getNextHandler(TagUnit.java:125)
at javax.faces.view.facelets.TagHandler.<init>(TagHandler.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagHandlerImpl.<init>(TagHandlerImpl.java:58)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.composite.ImplementationHandler.<init>(ImplementationHandler.java:76)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor186.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
...
```

Here's the project pom.xml.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <snip package info />

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>gfv3ee6</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.smartbear</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-b06</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.2-b06</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oro</groupId>
            <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.2-1002-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
            <version>4.0</version>  
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dnsjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>dnsjava</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this was caused by a piece of invalid JSF that used to compile and work, but doesn't compile under the newer version of Mojarra.

**Old Code**

```
<h:outputLink value="/alink" target="_blank">
    #{msg[of:concat(of:concat('prefix-', cc.attrs.rType), '-postfix')]}
</h:outputLink>
```

**New Code**

```
<h:outputLink value="/alink" target="_blank">
    <h:outputText value="#{msg[ca:concat('prefix-', cc.attrs.rType, '-postfix')]}" />
</h:outputLink>
```